# How to create a custom action bar with flexible actions in React (with TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-component

I would like to create a custom action bar with flexible actions that can be set via props or similar.

This is how I implemented it (and it's working like expected), but I'm wondering if there's a better or cleaner way in React (with TypeScript).

Especially when the actions increase over time. Then I would have to add more booleans that would eventually make things confusing.

```
type CustomBarProps = {
    withButton: boolean,
    withCheckbox: boolean,
    withRadio: boolean,
}

export const CustomBar = ({
    withButton = false,
    withCheckbox = false,
    withRadio = false,
}: CustomBarProps) => {
    const features: JSX.Element[] = [
        withButton && <Button />,
        withCheckbox && <Checkbox />,
        withRadio && <Radio />,
    ]
    return <Bar features={features} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah you don't need to explicitly define each prop has to be false you can also do it like this

```
type CustomBarProps = {
  Button?: boolean;
  Checkbox?: boolean;
  Radio?: boolean;
};

export const CustomBar: React.FC<CustomBarProps> = ({ Button, Checkbox, Radio }) => {
  const features = [Button && <Button />, Checkbox && <Checkbox />, Radio && <Radio />];
  return <Bar features={features} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip.  The one with the default values ​​definitely makes it cleaner - I also made a TODO comment on this because I wasn't sure yet.  But I'm still looking for a way to make it even cleaner.  For example, if I hide everything by default, but have the option to choose what to display. As far as I know, this only works with one value. For example: action: 'button' | 'check box' | 'radio'; But I can only select one action and not two or all 3 (or more). Is there a way to do this in TypeScript? At least I haven't found something yet :(